# Compare double* with double

Tags: c++, windows, double, clipboard

First i put clipboard to a variable, after i want to compare this variable with a double

```
double * k;

if (OpenClipboard(NULL) != FALSE) {
    HANDLE clip0 = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
    if (clip0 != NULL) {
        k = reinterpret_cast < double * > (GlobalLock(clip0));
        GlobalUnlock(clip0);
    }
    CloseClipboard();
}
printf("%f", k);

double mini;
mini = 0.1258;

if (k > mini) {
    printf("ok");
} else {
    printf("non");
}
```

but i got this error :  [Error] invalid operands of types 'double*' and 'double' to binary 'operator>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
k = reinterpret_cast < double * > (GlobalLock(clip0));
```

Users don't copy numbers the clipboard. They copy text.  GlobalLock will return to you the pointer to the **text** content of the clipboard data.  You have to parse it into a number.

Better:

```
char* text = reinterpret_cast<char*>(GlobalLock(clip0));
double d = atof(text);
```

Comment: thanks you but with  printf("%s", text); i got the clipboard and not with             printf("%f", d);

Comment: And what did you get with `printf("%f",d)` ?

Comment: Also, realize that if there's any leading whitespace in the text, has non-digit chars, or is simply not interpretable as a number, `atof` will give unexpected results.

Comment: i got 0.0000000

Comment: That means the text you passed to `atof` was not a number.

Comment: Maybe cause The number is like this : 1,2563 ( with a ' , ' ) ?

Comment: Ok its this thanks, now i want to replace the ' , ' with a ' . ', how i can do this ? (im noob ^^)

Comment: You probably need to learn the basics of `C` programming, including pointers and string fundamentals.